# Intel Virtualization Problems (Android Studio)

Tags: android, cpu, intel, virtualization

So, I am trying to use the Android Device Emulator (AVD), but it has the typical error: "hax kernel module is not installed". However, I reinstalled the Intel HAXM 1.1.5 dozens of times. I have that option enabled in the BIOS, and I can use virtualization in the Oracle VM VirtualBox. I even downloaded a program to test if my PC supported virtualization and went to the Intel web page to see if my processor was able to do that. It can.

I don't know why is this giving me such a problem. I tried many videos and googled and googled again, but noone seems to have the same problem as I do. However, I notice that when I try to run "sc query intelhaxm", it always says it's not installed (error code 1060). I always reset my PC after installing the HAXM.

My CPU is a Intel Core i3 M 330 (3M Cache, 2.13Ghz) ([intel specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/47663/Intel-Core-i3-330M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz)) and, if needed, I have a HP Pavillion dv6-2160ep ([specs](http://support.hp.com/pt-pt/product/HP-Pavilion-dv6-Entertainment-Notebook-PC-series/4041735/model/4123907)).

Thanks,
Ric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I kinda found a solution that lets me use the service intelhaxm. I just can't find a place where someone did what I did. Anyway, I'm going to post my solution, for other persons with the same problem as me don't get the trouble I had. So:

Before I say anything, I'm using Windows 7 and I'm portuguese, so I'm guessing the name of the directory's/options:

- Install the Intel HAXM normally and then restart your computer.
- After that, browse to the Intel HAXM folder ("C:\Program Files or Program Files (x86)\Intel\HAXM").
- Right click in the window while holding Shift. Click on "Open command prompt here".
- Write "PnPUtil.exe -i -a intelhaxm.inf". If it asks you to accept it, click OK.
- After that, right click in the intelhaxm.inf file and select Install.
- At this point, if you type "sc query intelhaxm" in the command prompt, it should show info about the service. However, it doesn't have a certificate, and you can't still use it.
- Download Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider [here](http://www.ngohq.com/?page=dseo).
- Open it, select "Enable Test Mode" and press Next. After it's done, restart your computer.
- If you did everything correct, there should be a watermark at the desktop saying something like "Test Mode". Open the same program again, but now select "Sign a System File".
- In the text field, paste the complete path to the intelhaxm.sys. Something like this: "C:\Program Files or Program Files (x86)\Intel\HAXM\intelhaxm.sys".
- After that, open the command prompt again the same way you did above.
- Type "sc delete intelhaxm" and then install the .inf file the same way you did.
- Now, try to type "sc start intelhaxm". It takes more time than usual, but now it should be running.

This is what I did to get it working. However, it only works while Windows is in Test Mode. If you want to get rid of the watermark, launch the same program again and choose "Remove Watermark".

If after you turn off the computer and go back later you can't launch your AVD, type "sc start intelhaxm" in the search bar of the Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the command lines
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
Turned off avast if you have it 
Downloaded the HAXM from Intel and not thru AVD
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement

Comment: I used the bcdedit command to do something similar to that. But I still did it. I don't have Avast, but I disable Avira everytime I install it. I already downloaded the Intel HAXM from their site.